# read the table in html format with R

Tags: r, html-table, rvest

I use rvest::read_html to read the table in html format. The html file is just a table.
here is my code.

```
library(rvest)

pp = read_html("Batch1_Parameters.html") %>%
  html_table()

pptable = pp[[1]]
```

I could get the table by these code. but is there any method to read the table with only one sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is simple already, I dont see any solution simplier than it but you can check this if it is needed one pipe

```
library(rvest)

pptable <- read_html("Batch1_Parameters.html") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]
```

Comment: thank you so much. that's totally what i want.

Comment: I am happy that you got what you want.